# label inside **NoRecordsTemplate** in **telerik radgrid**

Tags: telerik-grid

i have a label inside  **NoRecordsTemplate** in **telerik radgrid**

how can  I find label id in .cs file in **telerik radgrid control** in  **NoRecordsTemplate**??

```
       <NoRecordsTemplate>

              <div><asp:Label ID="lblerror" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>

          </NoRecordsTemplate>
```

Currently I am using following code to get label id but it is not working.

```
 protected void rgUsers_ItemDataBound(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.Item is GridNoRecordsItem)
         {
            Label lblerror = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblerror"));

            SetValidation(lblerror, Messages.NO_RECORD_FOUND);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but if you have a recent Telerik version, could you try just setting the text instead of using a control:

```
rgUsers.MasterTableView.NoMasterRecordsText = "Your Error Text"
```

More suggestions [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/changing-no-records-to-display-text.aspx).

Comment: thanks Widor.. but i need to find out the Lable ID which is inside the  NoRecordsTemplate.

Comment: The client-side ID? You define the Server-side one surely?